# Linear combination of simple function is a simple function

Tags: lebesgue-measure, simple-functions

Let $f_i= \sum_{j=1}^m a_j\chi_{A_j}$ be a simple function. We have to show that finite linear cimbination of simple functions is a simple function.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \sum_{j=1}^m a_j\chi_{A_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m  \alpha_i  a_j\chi_{A_j} $$
I guess it is almost finish but I do not see why this sum satisfies the definiction of simple function.

Comment: Note that you can change the order of sums. Set $b_j = \sum_{i=1}^n  \alpha_i  a_j.$

Comment: Ok, so I will have
$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m  \alpha_i  a_j\chi_{A_j}  = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n  \alpha_i  a_j\chi_{A_j}   = \sum_{j=1}^m b_j \chi_{A_j}  $$
But shouldn't it be $\chi_{B_j} $ where $b_j$ is value on set $B_j$?